# MagicSuggest: redirect after choosing item

Tags: javascript, cakephp, redirect, magicsuggest

I am using MagicSuggest (http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) with CakePHP in a Helper as a contact search.
My MagicSuggestHelper class looks like the following:

```
class MagicSuggestHelper extends AppHelper {

var $name = 'MagicSuggest';
var $helpers = array('Html');

public function suggest(array $options=null){
?>
    <div id='ms1'></div>
    <script>
        var ms = $('#ms1').magicSuggest({
            width: 300,
            highlight: true,
            allowFreeEntries: false,
            hideTrigger: true,
            expandOnFocus: true,
            useTabKey: true,
            maxSelection: 1,
            typeDelay: 0,
            name: "searchId",
            data: [
                <?php foreach($options['data'] as $suggestions){
                    echo"{\n";
                    echo"id: ".$suggestions['id'].",\n";
                    echo"name: \"".$suggestions['name']."\",\n";
                    echo"desc: \"".$suggestions['desc']."\",\n";
                    echo"image: \"".$suggestions['image']."\",\n";
                    echo"},";
                } ?>
            ],
            renderer: function(v){
            return '<div>' +
                '<div style="float:left;"><img src="' + v.image + '"/ style=\"max-width:80px;max-height:80px\""></div>' +
                '<div style="padding-left: 100px;">' +
                    '<div style="padding-top: 10px;font-style:bold;font-size:100%;color:#333">' + v.name + '</div>' +
                    '<div style="color: #999">' + v.desc + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>';
            }


        });
    </script>
    <?php   
}
```

This works fine for me. But when selecting an item I want to get redirected directly to the profile I just clicked on.
I tried it with an onclick()-event in the first  of the result which unfortunately didn't fired correctly when I used the CakePHP-HTML-Helper combined with $suggestions['id'].

On the MagicSuggest website I found an event that is fired when changing the selection The following code can be found in the FAQ:

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
 alert(selection); });
```

I think I can use a redirect-Function here instead of the alert.
But how to get the id here? Even alert(selection) returns me an alert with "object Object" which I think should not be the case.

So how can I get the id here and redirect to my Contact view? (/contacts/view/$id).
I didn't worked alot with JavaScript in the past so please also excuse beginner's mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
$(ms).on('selectionchange', function(e,m){
   var val = this.getValue(); // this is what you want
});
```